# One-time script authorization for templated spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

We built a purchase order system in Google Docs using Google App Script. The basic structure is a Google Web App, in which the user selects a few options, that app then clones Google Sheet templates to produce a Purchase Order (PO) document. The template includes a trigger to load an app script library we wrote, which is a set of custom menu options to control the PO workflow. Everything works well, except that every time a new PO is created (again, cloning from a template sheet), the users are required to re-authorize the app script. This adds several additional steps per person that are totally redundant. This is likely because the script is bound to the document, but not sure how to get around this since it creates custom menus and needs to be loaded on open.

Any way to have the user authorize the script once for all copies of the template?

Comment: Have you looked into making it an add-on, instead of a web-app?

Comment: An Addon is preferable because it requires a single authentication at the user level. New web apps, even from copied sheets, run sandboxed, meaning they _each_ need to be authorized by the user because it is a completely new file.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I will try that now and see if it helps.